# MSDN - ServiceLocation Outdated Why? Alternatives?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, msdn

I recently (1 month) start working in a project and as I was going through the code I saw an `using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation` and as I searched for the documentation on that library is says:

> This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained. It is provided as a courtesy for individuals who are still using these technologies. This page may contain URLs that were valid when originally published, but now link to sites or pages that no longer exist.

So I was wondering why does Microsoft say that it is outdated? and what other alternatives are to it?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about [that page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.servicelocation(v=pandp.51).aspx), the content is outdated because it deals with Enterprise Library 5, which was superseded with Enterprise Library 6 [three years ago](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx).

If you read the paragraph just below the one you quoted, it directly answers your question about the alternative:

> The latest **Enterprise Library** information can be found at the [Enterprise Library site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/entlib).

Finally, if you're interested specifically about `ServiceLocation` for Enterprise Library 6, you may be interested by the [corresponding NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocation/).